# ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, python-3.3

I want to use Django, uwsgi and nginx.

First I want to test uwsgi. I wrote a test.py file:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return "Hello World"
```

When I typed following command and tried to run uwsgi

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

it told me:

```
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

I searched a lot, but I didn't find the answer.

I use Ubuntu 13.04, Python 3.3.2 and uwsgi 1.9.14.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Django 1.6 beta 1. But I didn't use Django yet.

Comment: print all trace error

Comment: I solved it. It's about Python version, I found answer here:
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RunOnPython3k

Thank you, lalo.

Comment: @icedream91 link is redirecting to uwsgi and does not (directly contain any solutions to the problem mentioned)